# How to make use of the GCC fixed-point types extension on ARM Cortex-M?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, arm, fixed-point

I am using a ARM Cortex-M3, and a Cortex-M4. I want to make use of GCC's [fixed-point type extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed_002dPoint.html#Fixed_002dPoint). I am using the *summon-arm-toolchain*. The following line of code

```
_Fract f = 0.1;
```

throws the following compile error:

```
error: fixed-point types not supported for this target
```

Does GCC really not support the fixed-point types for Cortex-M3/M4, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I suspect your GCC was just built without support for fixed point, probably to debloat the toolchain a bit. You might try building your own GCC...

Comment: @R.., hey, I didn't even know GCC *had* a fixed point extension. Sweet. Things changed since 1995.

Comment: @R I tried a different toolchain, [gnuarm](http://www.gnuarm.com/) for an ARM7TDMI. I compiled _gcc4.4.2_ from sources for this toolchain. I still get the same compile error.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, they really helped me find a definite answer to my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for the record, I will answer my own question.

**TL;DR**: fixed-point types extension is supported for the ARM Cortex-M/R architecture in the *embedded* branch of gcc (version 4.6 and later). A toolchain based on that gcc branch is found [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded).

**Long answer**:

At the time of writing, the [*summon-arm-toolchain*](https://github.com/esden/summon-arm-toolchain) downloads by default linaro-gcc-4.5-2011.02 (or alternatively gcc-4.5.2). It does **not** have enabled by default the *fixed-point types* extension. I tried adding the parameter `--enable-fixed-point` to `configure`, but I got the compile error described by this [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34422). I tried using a more recent version of (linaro-)gcc, but the *summon-arm-toolchain* had problems applying its own provided gcc patch to this newer version. I also tried using the *dev* branch of this toolchain (which uses linaro-gcc-4.6-2011.10) without success. It looks like, at this point, fixed-point extension is not supported for ARM Cortex-M/R neither by linaro-gcc, nor the *main* branch of gcc.

I then tried the [gcc-arm-embedded toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded), which is based on the *embedded* branch of gcc. I was able to compile my *fixed-point types* sample program without problems, for targets ARM Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M4. Support for this extension for Cortex-M/R was added in late 2011, as can be seen on [this thread](https://answers.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+question/200553).

Answer (score 6):

According to [GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FixedPointArithmetic), you can enable the fixed point extensions by passing `--enable-fixed-point` as a parameter to GCC while configuring it.

Further, according to a comment on this gcc [bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34422) and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38617) one.

> fixed point support is only currently supported for the MIPS target.

Comment: Is this option supposed to be passed when compiling GCC, or when compiling your application?  I just tried this with gcc version 4.6.1 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2011.09-69), and got `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized option '--enable-fixed-point'`

Comment: You definitely need to do this while doing ./configure GCC i.e. compiling GCC. I'm not sure if it's also needed while compiling your application but I believe so. Please also see the links in my edited answer.

Comment: I cannot really confirm that was the problem, as I couldn't compile gcc (the one used by the summon-arm-toolchain) using that --enable-fixed-point. It seems to be possible to use the fixed-point types extension on ARM Cortex-Mx using [this toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)